# Magento Product Options In tabs

Tags: magento

I have a requirement in magento,

I need to add different product options to a magento product. Each product option should draw out its own tab on the product page. For example, color, size etc each would have its own tab and obsiously the options within each tab to choose from.... wondering if anyone has ever done anything like this or if anyone knows of a module which might help?

Once kind of example although not magento based would be http://www.timelesschesterfields.com/the-range/customiser/sofas/leather/knightsbridge

Any ideas or pointing me in the right direction would be a great help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using configurable products and swatch images so that the image switches dependant on the variables selected. I think this may be the easiest way.